# Background image appear on link hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to have a number of links within a single paragraph that each display a different image on link hover. I want the image to appear behind the text and disappear when mouse moves off link but I have been stuck for a while

I want the images to appear top left on hover

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZLvXW

Happy to use jQuery or css, any suggestions much appreciated

```
span:hover {
background-image: 
url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg");
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` also add `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

Do in same way to other links

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

span:hover {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
  <span class="link1"><a href="#">(1) link#1</a></span>  
  <a href="#">(2) link#2</a> <a href="#">(3) link#3</a>
  text text text text text text text text text text
</h1>
```

**EDIT**

> I want the images to appear top left on hover

Set `position` to `img` to top left of **page**

```css
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#000;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
 span:hover a{
color:red;
}
    span:hover img {
    display:block;
    }
    img{
        width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<h1>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
      <span class="link1">
        <a href="#">(1) link#1</a>
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg"/>
      </span> 
      
      <a href="#">(2) link#2</a> <a href="#">(3) link#3</a>
      text text text text text text text text text text
    </h1>
```

Set `position` to `img` to top left of **`span`**

```css
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#000;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
span{
position:relative;
}
 span:hover a{
color:red;
}
    span:hover img {
    display:block;
    }
    img{
width: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<h1>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
      <span class="link1">
        <a href="#">(1) link#1</a>
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg"/>
      </span> 
      
      <a href="#">(2) link#2</a> <a href="#">(3) link#3</a>
      text text text text text text text text text text
    </h1>
```

Comment: How would you display the whole image in the top left corner on hover?

Answer (score 0):

**Less code and much funtionalty**

Just add a `class` to the `<a>` tags and define the style in css.

There is no need for extra elements and classes for your goal.

This is the result: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPNJbe

Answer (score 0):

It can be simple as this: Making the 'span' tag a block element.

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:hover {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg"); 
}
```

Solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGoaQz

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` tag to insert the image on `hover` state. This way you not need to change you entire code.

See the comment line `// changes here`. I changed `span:hover` to `span:hover:before` and put `content`, `height` and `width`. After that, to show image in top left and behind the text, I use `top`, `left` and `z-index`. You need to change `height` and `width` with the image size.

See working here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daymOK

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

span {
  }
// Changes here
span:hover:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/91v7TX1PcWU/hqdefault.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  <span class="link1"><a href="#">(1) link#1</a></span>  <a href="#">(2) link#2</a> <a href="#">(3) link#3</a> text text text text text text text text text text
</h1>
```